# Is there a maximum number of Grandmas you can have or any other item?

Tags: cookie-clicker

You can buy different sources to produce your cookies.

But is there any actual maximum in grandmas or factories you can have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The game itself does not limit it in anyway, but javascript does. I'm not sure what happens after you get 2^53 of one factory as javascript loses its ability to keep track of individual integers. [2^53+1 = 2^53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t).

Another thing to note is that the cost to buy the next factory [becomes `Infinity`](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Number_Reference) relatively fast, which means you will need a supernatural cookies per second stat to make any progress in any reasonable timespan.

Comment: Actually the limitation that comes first is not the number of buildings, but the price attached to those buildings. At around 5000 buildings (5060 cursors ... 4921 antimatter condensers) the prices will become Infinity. At this point you'd need to cheat to buy anything.